# I want to acces the whole web from my IP and only to some URLs outside it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to manage my htaccess file in my apache server but I don't know whats wrong to handle it.

I'm finishing a web page, that will substitute the current one, with a public part and a private part (via login form, something simple and usual functuionallity), but before launching in prod our users need to login to upload some documentation related to bank accounts.

Right now I have denied all access on htaccess with IP but mine's, but the users (the ones that need to log) havent got my IP so I've made this changes:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> #Part 1: only access to login & admin
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
> RewriteRule .* https://www.old-domain.com [R=302,L]
>
> #Part 2: only access with my IP
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^my.office.ip.address
> RewriteRule .* https://www.old-domain.com [R=302,L]
> ```

the idea is externall IPs only can enter on login page and private part (URL have "admin" on it: "/admin/profile") but In my ofice I can navigate the whole page without restrictions.

I've usea an external htaccess checker and the rules seems to be OK

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/?share=4a22f779-f199-414e-a015-285fb47efdb0

- https://www.new-domain.com/en/login is OK
- https://www.new-domain.com/admin is OK
- https://www.new-domain.com/en/foobar redirects to the old (current) domain

But when I configure the htaccess file on the server with only part 1, I always got redirect to the old domain (from my office IP also), and whatever the URL is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, your rules clearly say, "if it's not login or admin, redirect" (doesn't apply, okay), and then "if not my office IP, redirect" (does apply).

Comment: Yes, my mistake to explain that I only tried part 1 on the server and is not working. The idea is to have part 1 & 2, or similar, but working